# HTMLUnit - How to get a list of outgoing connections as List?

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am trying to get a list of the connections with HTMLunit. So far I have it working with the debugger (DebuggingWebConnection). However I just want the function to return the connections as a list. The debugger downloads everything as well.

```
public static void crawlPage() throws Exception {
   final WebClient wc = new WebClient();
   String resultFolder = "results";
   final WebConnection connection = new DebuggingWebConnection(wc.getWebConnection(), resultFolder);
   wc.setWebConnection(connection);
   HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) wc.getPage("http://www.test.com");

}
```

Returns in the results/index.html;

```
GET http://www.test.com/ 200 (text/html) 14.53 Kib, 866ms
GET http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js 200 (text/javascript) 77.38 Kib, 399ms
GET http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=5.4.5&utms=1&utmn=1203166335&utmhn=www.test.com&utmcs=utf-8&utmsr=1024x768&utmvp=1256x605&utmsc=24-bit&utmul=en-us&utmje=0&utmfl=-&utmdt=Create%20Tests%20for%20Organizational%20Training%20and%20Certification%20Programs%20%E2%80%93%20Test.com&utmhid=121499150&utmr=-&utmp=%2F&utmht=1379757739907&utmac=UA-3518049-1&utmcc=__utma%3D99889051.1275286197.1379757740.1379757740.1379757740.1%3B%2B__utmz%3D99889051.1379757740.1.1.utmcsr%3D(direct)%7Cutmccn%3D(direct)%7Cutmcmd%3D(none)%3B&utmu=q~ 200 (image/gif) 0.03 Kib, 23ms
GET http://www.test.com/content/js/jquery.min.js 200 (application/x-javascript) 166.71 Kib, 981ms
GET http://www.test.com/content/style.css 200 (text/css) 15.44 Kib, 323ms
GET http://www.test.com/content/flexslider.css 200 (text/css) 2.68 Kib, 395ms
GET http://www.test.com/content/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css 200 (text/css) 8.76 Kib, 313ms
GET http://www.test.com/content/jwplayer/jwplayer.js 200 (application/x-javascript) 326.94 Kib, 724ms
GET http://www.test.com/content/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js 200 (application/x-javascript) 21.44 Kib, 320ms
GET http://www.test.com/content/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js 200 (application/x-javascript) 33.31 Kib, 364ms
GET http://www.test.com/content/js/functions.js 200 (application/x-javascript) 1.87 Kib, 223ms
GET http://www.test.com/assets/_video_thumbnail/47-9a8803a2.png 200 (image/png) 223.8 Kib, 692ms
GET http://l.longtailvideo.com/download/5/9/logo.png 200 (image/png) 1.8 Kib, 26ms
GET http://www.test.com/assets/_video_thumbnail/92-7b078568.png 200 (image/png) 213.78 Kib, 1421ms
GET http://www.test.com/assets/_video_thumbnail/90-d8d9524d.png 200 (image/png) 229.09 Kib, 595ms
GET http://www.test.com/assets/_video_thumbnail/93-52d92cf8.png 200 (image/png) 221.17 Kib, 587ms
```

Anyone has any pointers on how to get this list without the debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you'll find an easy way to do this. Mostly because HtmlUnit is a headless browser and not such a low-level library to operate on the connections (as the Apache HttpClient classes that are used by HtmlUnit).

Probably, you should reconsider the use of HtmlUnit. If you still want to use HtmlUnit then I guess you'll have to see the code of the `DebuggingWebConection` to use it as guidance and create your own `WebConnection` implementation, which would likely inherit from `WebConnectionWrapper`. Then you'll have to handle the creation and maintainance of the list of connections yourself.